# Precedence of empty explicit rule and implicit rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My understanding of implicit rule is that implicit rule will only be used 
if there is no explict rule that matches a target.
If there are both explicit rule and implicit rule that match a target, 
that the explicit rule will be used, the implicit rule will be ignored.

But running the following example shows that implicit rule is used, and empty explicit rule is not used.

Makefile

```
all:

%:
      #match-anything implicit rule
```

the output of make is 
    #match-anything implicit rule

Makefile

```
all:
      #explicit rule

%:
      #match-anything implicit rule
```

the output of make is
       #explicit rule

Comment: it seems that a single line containing all: does not count as an empty rule. if the first makefile is changed to all:; then the output of make is `all' is up to date

Comment: I imagine that `all:` is seen as a prerequisite setting line and not a rule (as it has no body).

Comment: a rule is composed of target, prerequisites and recipe.

Comment: What does explicit rule mean? It seems an explicit rule must have explicit target, explicit prerequisite and explicit recipe.

Comment: See [Rule Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax), [What Makefiles Contain](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Contents), and the last paragraph of [Multiple Rules for One Target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Rules). For what should be enough detail to make this make sense. (Specifically that last link.)

Comment: hi Etan, I have read those sections you mentioned in GNU make manual. But the manual does not mention multiple mixed implicit rules and explicit rules for one target

Comment: That's exactly what the last paragraph of my last link is talking about. It **explicitly** says "If none of the explicit rules for a target has a recipe, then `make` searches for an applicable implicit rule to find one." That's the **exact** behaviour you are seeing and were asking about. An explicit rule with no recipe does not override an implicit rule.

Comment: Thank you very much, Etan, that answers my question. It seems that I have to read the manual more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is documented in the GNU make manual in the [Multiple Rules for One Target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Rules) section.

> If none of the explicit rules for a target has a recipe, then make
>   searches for an applicable implicit rule to find one see Using
>   Implicit Rules).

Additional information (as relevant to understand the various interconnected behaviours) is available in the [Rule Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax) and [What Makefiles Contain](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Contents) sections.

Answer (score 0):

From [Using Empty Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Recipes) in GNU make manual:

> It is sometimes useful to define recipes which do nothing. This is done simply by giving a recipe that consists of nothing but whitespace. For example:
>
> target: ;
>
> defines an empty recipe for target. You could also use a line beginning with a recipe prefix character to define an empty recipe, but this would be confusing because such a line looks empty.
>
> You may be wondering why you would want to define a recipe that does nothing. The only reason this is useful is to prevent a target from getting implicit recipes (from implicit rules or the .DEFAULT special target; see Implicit Rules and see Defining Last-Resort Default Rules).